# Avoid null values from Kendo Grid search

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm new to using Telerik, and I am currently working on a [ASP.Net Core Grid](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid)

So I have it working, but now I want to add the search bar toolbar, so I added it as:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
  .Name("grid")
  .ToolBar(t => t.Search())
  .Search(s =>
                    {
                        s.Field(o => o.PrimaryContact.FirstName, "contains");
                    })
```

The problem is that `PrimaryContact.FirstName` can be null, so when I try to search for something, it throws a console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'FirstName')

This same thing happen on the columns and I solve it adding `ClientTemplate` as:

```
columns.Bound(x => x.PrimaryContact.FirstName)
       .ClientTemplate("#= PrimaryContact ? PrimaryContact.FirstName : '' #")
```

But Search has no a client template to handle this

I tried to change the null value for the string empty with jQuery as:

```
 function onDataBound(e) {
 for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) 
{
           const row = $(rows[i]);
           const dt = e.sender.dataItem(row);
           const firstName = dt.get("PrimaryContact.FirstName");
              if (firstName === null)
                 {
                     row[0].cells[2].innerHTML = "";
                 }
}
}
```

But it does not work.

How can I avoid the null values from the search? Regards

FullCode:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
                    .Name("grid")
                    .ToolBar(t =>
                    {
                        t.Excel();
                        t.Pdf();
                        t.Search();
                    })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Custom()
                        .PageSize(20)
                        .Schema(schema =>
                        {
                            schema.Data(x => "function(d) { return validateData(d); }");
                        })
                    )
                    .Pageable(pager => pager
                        .Numeric(true)
                        .Info(true)
                        .PreviousNext(true)
                        .PageSizes(new [] { 10 ,25 ,50 })
                        .Position(GridPagerPosition.Bottom)
                        .Messages(m =>
                        {
                            m.ItemsPerPage("entries");
                            m.Display("Showing {0} - {1} of {2} entries");
                        })
                        )
                    .Sortable()
                    .Search(s =>
                    {
                        s.Field(o => o.Name, "contains");
                        s.Field(o => o.PrimaryContact.FirstName, "contains");
                        s.Field(o => o.PrimaryContact.PhoneNumber, "contains");
                        s.Field(o => o.PrimaryContact.EmailAddress, "contains");
                        s.Field(o => o.IsActive, "contains");
                    })
                    .Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound"))
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(x => x.AdvertiserId)
                            .Hidden();
                        columns.Bound(x => x.Name)
                            .Title("Advertiser Name");
                        columns.Bound(x => x.PrimaryContact.FirstName)
                            .ClientTemplate("#= PrimaryContact ? PrimaryContact.FirstName : '' #")
                            .Title("Contact Name");
                        columns.Bound(x => x.PrimaryContact.PhoneNumber)
                            .ClientTemplate("#= PrimaryContact ? PrimaryContact.PhoneNumber : '' #")
                            .Title("Contact Phone");
                        columns.Bound(x => x.PrimaryContact.EmailAddress)
                            .ClientTemplate("#= PrimaryContact ? PrimaryContact.EmailAddress : '' #")
                            .Title("Contact Email");
                        columns.Bound(x => x.IsActive)
                            .Title("Status")
                            .ClientTemplate("<span class='badgeTemplate'></span>")
                            .Sortable(false);
                        columns.Template("<div class='btn-group'></div>")
                            .Title("").Width(100);
                    })
                    )

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateData(data)
        {
            for (const item of data) {
            if (!item.hasOwnProperty("PrimaryContact")) {
                    item["PrimaryContact.FirstName"] = { "FirstName": ""};
                }
            }
    
            return data;
        }
  </script>
```

I also tried using `BeforeEdit event`

```
.Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound").BeforeEdit("onBeforeEdit")

function onBeforeEdit(e) {
      if(e.model.isNew()){
        e.PrimaryContact.FirstName = "";
      }
    }
```

But it does not work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably avoid using nested properties whenever possible. You should have a custom ViewModel that flattens everything (whatever your `Model` class is). Second, the asp.net API is not as full featured as the native javascript library. It's just a passthrough to generate javascript on the page anyway, so don't be afraid to add javascript if you need to.

What you're trying to do isn't possible. You can build a proper flat ViewModel, or you can intercept data and mutate before loading it into the grid. You do that using the [`schema`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/schema) property on the datasource. You'll define a custom javascript method.

One more thing, I think your problem is not that `FirstName` is missing, it's that `PrimaryContact` is null. You can probably fix this server side without too much hassle. But here's how to fix it client side, if, for example, you're getting this from a 3rd party API.

```cs
.DataSource(ds =>
{
    ds
        .Custom()
        .Transport(t =>
        {
            // ...
        })
        .Schema(x => .Data(x => "function(d) { return validateData(d); }"))
        // ...
        ;
})
```

Or if you just use the javascript definition

```js
dataSource: {
    // ...
    schema: { data: validateData }
}
```

Then here is the javascript method to cleanup your model with whatever properties you need to fix:

```js
function validateData(data)
{
    for (const item of data) {
    if (!item.hasOwnProperty("PrimaryContact")) {
            item["PrimaryContact"] = { "FirstName": ""};
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Full dojo [example here](https://dojo.telerik.com/eqepIWUP)

Comment: I tried to validate data, as you mentioned, on schema, but still getting the same result; I posted the complete code

Comment: I do a change to check if PrimaryContact is null as:     `if (item.PrimaryContact === null)`, so it hits, now I want to add manually the `FirstName` property to `item.PrimaryContact` object  how can I achieve that?

Comment: Ok I solved now using `for (const item of data) {
            if (item.PrimaryContact === null) {
                item["PrimaryContact"] = { "FirstName": "" };
            }
        }`

Now is searching and does not throw an error but it does not remove the empty rows on search